# CSS in an unordered (bulleted) list

Tags: css

I want to use a background image (/images/background.jpg) in all tabs, except the tab with **class="selected"**. "Selected" tab should use only background color #B74A12 without any background image. Below are my css code. Unfortunately, it adds background image to all tabs, including "selected". "a hover" keeps showing the image instead of different background color :(

```
<ul id="main" class="shadetabs">
<li><a href="/>One</a></li>
<li class="selected"><a href="/">Two</a></li>
<li><a href="/">Three</a></li>
</ul>

.shadetabs{padding:0;color:#fff;font-family:Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;white-space:nowrap;list-style-type:none;font-weight:700;}
.shadetabs li,.shadetabs li.selected{display:inline;}
.shadetabs li a,.shadetabs li.selected a{margin-right:1px;font-family:Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;text-decoration:none;float:left;}

.shadetabs li a{padding: 5px 7px 7px 7px;background-color:#f1f1f1;background:#fff url(/images/background.jpg) top left repeat-x;color:#444;border-top:1px solid #d1d1d1;border-left:1px solid #d1d1d1;border-right:1px solid #d1d1d1;}
.shadetabs li.selected a{padding:5px 7px 7px 7px;background-color:#B74A12;color:#fff;border-top:1px solid #B74A12;border-left:1px solid #B74A12;border-right:1px solid #B74A12;}
.shadetabs li a:hover{background-color:#A32A36;color:#ffffff;}
.shadetabs li.selected a:hover{background-color:#BFD024;color:#fff;}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An element can have both a `background-image` and a `background-color` at the same time. You can change your CSS from `background-color` to the shorthand `background` for `.shadetabs li.selected a`.

For example: `background: #B74A12 url('you-background-here.jpg');`